# "Quali che siano" vs. "Chi che siano"

Tags: pronouns

Nell'esempio, "Chi" e "Quali" sono completamente intercambiabili?

> Quali che siano le persone che conosci ...
>
> Chi che siano le persone che conosci ...

Oppure cambia qualcosa tra il primo esempio e il secondo?

Answer (score 5):

«Chi che siano le persone che conosci …» pare privo di significato. Nota che "chi che sia" non si usa più in italiano moderno ma solo "[chicchessìa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chicchessia/)", in pochi casi ben definiti. "Chi che siano" è errato perché in questo caso il "[chi](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chi1/)" richiede il singolare («In frasi interrogative, dirette o indirette […] Anche quando ha valore di plurale, l’accordo del verbo si fa ugualmente al singolare»).

Al contrario, «Quali che siano le persone che conosci …» significa «Indipendentemente da quali siano le persone che conosci …».

---

Da [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quale/):

> quale agg. e pron. [lat. qualis]. – Indica, con valore interrogativo e relativo, singoli elementi (cose, persone, animali, ecc.), o categorie di elementi, in relazione alla qualità per cui si caratterizzano e distinguono

«[Mi chiedo] quali siano le persone che conosci» --> vuoi identificare, **all'interno di un gruppo di persone**, quelle che l'interlocutore conosce, gli chiedi di indicarle; oppure ne vuoi verificare qualche qualità comune (ma in questo caso l'espressione è ambigua/incompleta). Potrebbe addirittura essere interpretata come «[Mi chiedo] che razza di persone siano quelle che conosci».

«[Mi chiedo] chi siano le persone che conosci» --> vuoi ottenere qualche informazione, inclusa l'identità, circa le persone che l'interlocutore conosce.