# È 'chicchesiano' una parola?

Tags: word-choice

Secondo Treccani Online 'Chicchessia' significa 'chi che sia'.

Può la parola 'Chicchesiano', che non c'è nel Treccani, essere usata per dire 'chi che siano'?

Comment: Semmai “chicchessiano”, con due “s” come “chicchessia”, perché “che” vuole il raddoppiamento fonosintattico.

Comment: Nota che "chi che sia" non si usa più in italiano moderno ma solo "[chicchessìa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chicchessia/)", in pochi casi ben definiti. "Chi che siano" è errato perché in questo caso il "[chi](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chi1/)" richiede il singolare. Puoi usare invece "quali che siano" come osservato [qui](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/quali-vs-chi-nella-frase-indicata-dentro-la-domanda).

Comment: A conferma empirica di quello che scrive @randomatlabuser (ma comunque basta l'osservazione che “chi” è singolare), a Google books [non risultano occorrenze di “chi che siano”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chi+che+siano%2Cchicchessiano%2Cchicchesiano&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=) scritto in alcun modo.

Comment: Nessuno, tranne lo Spirito Creativo in Persona, potrebbe affermare la proprietà di Chi che Sia o di chicchessia o di checché cosa. :) :) ;) fdf

Answer (score 3):

Chicchessiano non è una parola italiana (e se vogliamo dirla tutta, pure "chicchessia" non suona poi tanto bene). Secondo me è meglio parafrasare (chiunque sia, ad esempio).

Se hai necessità di usare il plurale, puoi usare "quali che siano".

Answer (score 3):

"Chicchessia" è di per sé una parola piuttosto rara, che è difficile trovare in qualsiasi registro; la parola "chicchessiano", se anche esistesse, sarebbe di fatto introvabile.
Suggerisco di usare invece parole più comuni (qualunque persona o nessuno, [a seconda dell'uso](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chicchessia/)); chicchessia è talmente raro che può essere usato solo in un contesto scherzoso, per imitare un lessico forbito.

Comment: Per la verità io, senza imitare un lessico forbito, semplicemente non do le mie chiavi di casa a chicchessia